# How to change the custom content of a ToggleButton in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, togglebutton

I have changed the style of a `ToggleButton` in a `ResourceDictionary`. In my style I'm changing the `ControlTemplate` of the `ToggleButton` and I place an image before the `Content`.

**Now here is my question:** The image needs to be changed for different `ToggleButtons` I use in XAML, should I define different styles for each `ToggleButton` with different image or is there some way I can change its image in XAML?

```
<Style x:Key="BaseToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Border">
                    <Image Width="13" Height="13" Source="{StaticResource ColumnsLayoutMiniIcon}"/>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is there a way I can change the image here instead of in style?

```
<RadioButton Content="Plan View"
             GroupName="View"
             Style="{StaticResource BaseToggleButton}">
</RadioButton>
```

Comment: `<TextBlock> <ContentPresenter/> </TextBlock>` - something's wrong there.

Comment: @HighCore I've stripped some boilerplate code. I may have removed something there accidentally. But the idea is how to reuse the whole style when only the image changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can piggy back in on an unused property that comes in real handy for this sort of situation called `Tag` which you can you use to pass in your image path or resource declaration etc once we go bind it to the template like;

```
<Style x:Key="BaseToggleButton" TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <!-- Let's give it a default -->
    <Setter Property="Tag" Value="{StaticResource ColumnsLayoutMiniIcon}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Border">
                    <Image Width="13" Height="13" 
                           Source="{TemplateBinding Tag}"/>
                    <ContentPresenter/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now we can either leave as is and it should display that mini icon as your default, you can specify a new one at the instance level like;

```
<ToggleButton Content="Plan View"
              Tag="{StaticResource ADifferentImagePathOrResourcePointingToOne}"
              Style="{StaticResource BaseToggleButton}"/>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: Very brilliant idea! Thank you so much. This will definitely help me think about some other problems I have in a different way.

Comment: Glad you got a remedy, always a good day when you learn something new. :)